# Como enviar formateado Verificación Email

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, gmail

estoy buscando dar formato al mensaje de confirmación Email que se encuentra en la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi **salida** es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algún consejo para dar formato al mensaje e inclusive agregar una imagen, gracias de antemano.

**Código:**

```
To: '<?= $prospecto->Email ?>',
From: "xxxxxxxx",
Subject: "<?= $prospecto->Nombre ?> Verifica tu correo electrónico",
string htmlString = @"<html></html>"; 
Body: `
      <p align="justify"> Gracias <?= $prospecto->Nombre ?> por registrarte en Schoollastic. <br>
      Estás recibiendo este correo ya que acabas de crear una cuenta en ***********. <br> 
      Una plataforma diseñada para mejorar tus conocimientos y habilidades profesionales.<br>

      Para completar el registro será necesario confirmes tu correo electronico. <br>https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
      Basta con hacer clic en el link de abajo.

      <a type="button" href='<?= URL ?>/formAlumno/verificarEmail/?ID=<?= $prospecto->GUID ?>' targe='_blank'><h3>ACTIVAR CUENTA </h3></a>

      Al confirmar tu correo no solo nos permite conocer que No eres un robot, <br>
      si no que a partir de este podremos enviarte notificaciones respecto a la plataforma educativa con las ultimas novedades;<br>
      novedades que esperamos sean de ayuda en tu ámbito profesional.<p>
`
```

Comment: Yo he usado esta plataforma para generar layout's de correo, especialmente por que te genera el código para dar soporte a outlook, ya que no te toma muchos estilos de css. [beefree](https://beefree.io/templates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar formato solo tenes que usar CSS usando `style="..."` en los elementos que quieras, eso es lo más seguro, ya que depende de cada cliente o plataforma de email el soporte que tenga.

Una imagen también la puedes agregar normalmente, pero recordá usar la URL a la imagen completa `<img src='https:// ....jpg' />`